# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "fruit"

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE Gruppelærer(
  brnavn VARCHAR(8),
  emnekode VARCHAR(8),
  år INT,
  vh CHAR(4),
  antallgr INT,
  CONSTRAINT larer_id PRIMARY KEY(brnavn, emnekode, år, vh)
);

CREATE TABLE Søknad(
  brnavn VARCHAR(8),
  emnekode char(4),
  år VARCHAR(8),
  vh INT,
  antallgr INT,
  prioritet INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (brnavn, emnekode, år, vh, antallgr) REFERENCES Gruppelærer(brnavn, emnekode, år, vh, antallgr),
  UNIQUE (brnavn, emnekode, år, vh, prioritet)
);
```

ERROR:

> There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "fruit"

Why does this not work?

Comment: Because your 3-column FK tries to reference a 4-column-PK.

Comment: which columns are you referring to?

Comment: Aside from the `vh` column, there's also the issue that your data types are badly mismatched. `fruitid` is an `int` in `InStore` but a `varchar(8)` in the `fruit` table.

Comment: With edit: Well, now you have the opposite problem. You're trying to reference five columns when there's only a constraint defined on 4 of those columns. And, still, you have data type mismatches.

Answer (score 0):

either, you need to remove `[vh]` field from `PRIMARY_KEY` or add it in the `FOREIGN_KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE fruit(
  fruitname VARCHAR(128),
  fruitid VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  yearplanted INT,
  vh CHAR(4),
  numberoffruits INT,
  CONSTRAINT fruit_id PRIMARY KEY(fruitname, fruitid, yearplanted, vh)
);

CREATE TABLE InStore(
  fruitname VARCHAR(8),
  fruitid INT,
  yearplanted CHAR(4),
  quantity INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (fruitname, fruitid, yearplanted, vh) REFERENCES fruit(fruitname, fruitid, yearplanted, vh),
  UNIQUE (fruitname, fruitid, yearplanted, quantity, vh)
);
```

Comment: this is the actual table
CREATE TABLE Gruppelærer(
  brnavn VARCHAR(8),
  emnekode VARCHAR(8),
  år INT,
  vh CHAR(4),
  antallgr INT,
  CONSTRAINT larer_id PRIMARY KEY(brnavn, emnekode, år, vh)
);

CREATE TABLE Søknad(
  brnavn VARCHAR(8),
  emnekode char(4),
  år VARCHAR(8),
  vh INT,
  antallgr INT,
  prioritet INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (brnavn, emnekode, år, vh, antallgr) REFERENCES Gruppelærer(brnavn, emnekode, år, vh, antallgr),
  UNIQUE (brnavn, emnekode, år, vh, prioritet)
);
Cant get it to work even though I implement the given code into the file.

Comment: @Dankmeme: Post the above code in the question not as a comment